# Writing a gulp task as a pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am quite new to Node and gulp which I am trying to learn.
As an experiment, I am trying to write a little gulp task that just prints on the console the content of the streams it receives from the `gulp.src()` method. So, I have implemented it this way (the commented code works and the not commented code does not work). What am I doing wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var fs = require('fs');
var PATHS = {
    src : 'src/**/*.ts',
    html : 'src/**/*.html',
    css : 'src/**/*.css'
};

gulp.task('test', function() {
    // This is working !!!
    /*
     * fs.createReadStream('ex.txt').pipe(through(function(chunk, enc, callback) {
     * console.log("Text is: " + chunk.toString());
     *
     * this.push(chunk)
     *
     * callback() })).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.txt')).on('finish',
     * function() { console.log("Working"); })
     */
    // But this is not working, why !!!
    var writable = through.obj(function(chunk, enc, callback) {
        if (chunk.isStream()) {
            console.log("Chunk is stream ");
            console.log("Path is: " + chunk.path);
        } else if (chunk.isBuffer()) {
            console.log("Chunk is buffer ");
        } else {
            console.log("Chunk is something else then stream or buffer");
        }
        this.push(chunk);
        callback();
    });
    gulp.src('ex.txt').pipe(writable);
});
```

**BTW - How can I tell what kind of object is  '*chunk*' and what methods I have available to call on that object (where are they documented – I am used to Java style documentation)?**

These might be trivial questions for experienced Node.js and gulp users but I am having trouble to understand them.
If anybody can help me to get through this learning curve I would greatly appreciate it.